# why iostat not showing one of my disk?

Tags: df, iostat

Please check the picture below. The df shows /dev/xsda mounted

But iostat not showing the device. Why?

```
[admin] /dev]$df -h | grep '/dev'
tmpfs           64M     0   64M   0% /dev
/dev/nvme1n1   7.0T   50G  6.6T   1% /etc/hosts
shm            2.0G  2.0G     0 100% /dev/shm
/dev/xsda       98G   74G   20G  80% /xxxxxxx

[admin] /dev]$iostat
Linux 3.10.0-327.X XXX.alios7.x86_64 XXXXXXXXXX  07/15/2021  _x86_64_  (64 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal  %idle
          19.33    0.00    9.18    0.05    0.00  71.44

Device:            tps    kB_read/s     kB_wrtn/s      kB_read      kB_wrtn
sda              25.66       421.56         80.97   2908339319    558587096
nvme0n1         539.72      2136.15       4379.18  14737291080  30211918056
nvme11n1          0.00         0.01          0.00        95988            0
nvme1n1          63.11       532.54        277.74   3673963864   1916145252
nvme10n1          0.00         0.01          0.00        95988            0
```

Comment: xsda? What on earth is that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following parameter `-N` which will give you the registered device mapper name.

```
$iostat -m -N
```

> ```
>    -N     Display the registered device mapper names for any device
>           mapper devices.  Useful for viewing LVM2 statistics.
> ```

References :
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iostat.1.html